# Complexity in tilde notation of nested for loops

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity

How do I find the complexity in [tilde notation](http://www.quora.com/Which-is-best-alternative-to-Big-O-notation-for-representing-complexities) of the following algorithm:

```
for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {

    for (int k = j + 1; k < N; k++) {

        array[k] = array[j];

    }

    array[j] = k
}
```

I've made a table with how many times the inner for-loop loops if `N = 9`:

```
|     j      | # of loops  | 
|:-----------|------------:|
|     0      |      8      |          
|     1      |      7      |       
|     2      |      6      |         
|     3      |      5      |         
|     4      |      4      |     
|     5      |      3      | 
|     6      |      2      |
|     7      |      1      |
|     8      |      0      |
```

Comment: Comments from deleted answer: The answer depends on what is in "come code". For example: `for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) { for (int k = j + 1; k < N; k++) { sum += k; } }` will be different (in tilde notation) than: `for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) { for (int k = j + 1; k < N; k++) { sum += k; sumSquares += k*k; } }`. Moreover, they might have different constants depending on the machine it runs.

Comment: @amit I've added some sample code. Let's say I want to count the number of times I access an array for a certain N. How would my complexity in tilde notation then look like?

Comment: Complexity is ~O(n^2).

Comment: @I.K.: this does not really answer the question in tilde notation; you have to provide the hidden constant as well.

Comment: I think the complexity is ~2N² + N. 
Because in the inner-loop I have 2N² array-accesses and in the outer-loop N array-accesses.

Comment: @I.K.: this is precisely why the big-Oh notation does not answer the question.

Comment: @Yves Daoust, it does answer the question because when the leading term n^2 divides n^2-n, this resultant expression tends to 1 as N grows. This is how the tilde notation is used. And I was not using Big-Oh, I have a tilde in front.

Comment: @I.K.: nope, O(N²) does not mean N², it means cN² where c is unspecified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you evaluate, the number of inner iterations decreases linearly from `8` down to `0`, i.e. it is `4` on average, for a total of `4.9=36`.

More generally, the average is `(N-1)/2` and the total `N.(N-1)/2`.

Consequently, `I(N) ~ N²/2`, in terms of the iteration count.

In terms of memory accesses (R+W), it's the double: `A(N) ~ N²`. (The extra access in the outer loop adds a negligible `N` contribution.)

Comment: Then it would be ~2N² / 2 in terms of array-accesses count? Because there are two array-accesses in each inner iteration.

Comment: @Dongo: hem, what's the difference between 2N²/2 and N² ?

Comment: @I.K. Ok but the question that I am asked is the following "Give the complexity (number of array accesses) in function of size N". So I have take them into account.